# "getPendingTransactions" returns null

Tags: relayjs

When I have call `applyUpdate` on a mutation and then call `getPendingTransactions` I get `null`, no transactions returned basically. I have tried to track down the problem and `this._queuedRecords` in the file `RelayRecordStore.js` gives me `null` which I think is the cause of it.

This line: https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/store/RelayRecordStore.js#L271

Could it be that `getPendingTransactions` does not return `UNCOMMITED` commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of a wrong implementation of mutations. To get `this.queuedRecords` to show not null, I needed `getOptimisticResponse` in my mutation. I was also using `REQUIRED_CHILDREN`, but not sure if that was part of the problem. Anyways, I changed it to `RANGE_???` instead.